# PHP server not found upon inclusion of array?

Tags: php, arrays

I am just checking out some functions and the code is as simple as this:

```
<?php 

echo "hello" ; 

$var = '1';

var_dump($var);
//$arr = ('a'=>'1','b'=>'2', 'c'=>'3' ,) ;

//print_r($arr);

?>
```

Now at this point, if I were to uncomment `$arr`, and then access my file in the browser, it gives me a server error. This is soooo weird. And I don't know wassup. But I am sure it's a dumb mistake. Can anyone give me a heads up on this?

I also did `$arr = (1,2,3,4,5)` and `$arr = ('1','2','3','4','5')` but to no avail; same issue.

Comment: you forgot the `array` keyword

Comment: [RTFM](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) please.

Comment: We really need more information here. Is your local server running, or are you on a live web server? What error are you seeing - the exact text?

Comment: @DouglasA.Crosby He's just missing a proper array declaration - there's no point in knowing anything else... :-)

Answer (score 5):

What if you <del>remove that extra comma (`,`) from the end of your array declaration +</del> declare your array properly?

**Like this :**

```
<?php 

    echo "hello"; 

    $var = '1';

    var_dump($var);
    $arr = array('a'=>'1','b'=>'2','c'=>'3');

    print_r($arr);

?>
```

**How to create an array :**

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);

// as of PHP 5.4
$array = [
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
];
?>
```

---

**Reference :** http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: array would still work with the extra comma though. He just wasn't able to initialize his array properly.

Comment: @JackSpairow That's true. Bracketworks' point was 100% spot-on.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `array()` construct to create arrays, not merely `()`.

```
// all versions
$array = array('foo' => 'bar');

// 5.4+
$array = ['foo' => 'bar'];
```

While @Dr.Kameleon mentions removing the superfluous `,` (*comma*), it is perfectly acceptable to leave it in; in many cases recommended.

```
$array = [
    'foo' => 'bar',
];
```

It just helps with quickly re-arranging/adding/removing entries.

Comment: Well, you really got me wondering with that thing about the "comma". But, yep, you ARE right; although it still strikes me as ODD, no matter what... :-)

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon I love being able to leave it in; makes it troublesome jumping into JavaScript, as IE doesn't support trailing commas in such declarations.

Comment: If you don't like the ending comment, you could also add it at the beginning of each line: `$arr = ["foo" => "bar" / ,"fooo" => "baar" / ,"four" => "4" / ];`

Comment: GOood lord...missed the array keyword...the peril of programming beyond 12 hours on a stretch...my bad, thanks!